# How to put dynamic object view in static linear layout

Tags: java, android

I want to add in a relative layout a view  object from class dynamically

```
RelativeLayout r = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relative);
dv = new DrawingView(this);
r.addView(dv);
setContentView(R.layout.reportdrawing);
```

Comment: `setContentView(R.layout.reportdrawing);` must be called before using all `findViewById(...)` calls.

Answer (score 0):

You need to choose either use `setContentView()` and your view will be the parent,
Or to add your view to a relative layout.

Here is a working example.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             setContentView(R.activity.main);
             DrawingView drawingView = new DrawingView();
             RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative);
             linearLayout.addView(drawingView);
```